# adding horizontal line on left and right side of Text but text should not be on middle

Tags: html, css

i am new to CSS. I want to add horizontal lines on both side of a Header text but dont want the text to be on center.
the css I am currently using aligns text on center.

---------------------------------------------Some Text-----------------------------------------------

I want it to be like

---------Some Text---------------------------------------------------------------------

How can I set the position of text like this.

```
<div class="decoratedLine vlabelBold"><span>Some Text</span></div>
```

CSS:

```
<style>
.decoratedLine{
     overflow: hidden;
     text-align: center;
 }
.decoratedLine > span{
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
.decoratedLine > span:before, .decoratedLine > span:after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid;
    width: 591px; /* half of limiter*/
    margin: 0 20px;
}
.decoratedLine > span:before{
    right: 100%;
}
.decoratedLine > span:after{
    left: 100%;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make it by by changing the style of below selector -

```
.decoratedLine {
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-left: 40px;
}
```

```css
.decoratedLine {
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-left: 40px;
}

.decoratedLine>span {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.decoratedLine>span:before,
.decoratedLine>span:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    border-bottom: 1px solid;
    width: 591px;
    /* half of limiter*/
    margin: 0 20px;
}

.decoratedLine>span:before {
    right: 100%;
}

.decoratedLine>span:after {
    left: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="decoratedLine vlabelBold"><span>Some Text</span></div>
```

Comment: You should also add `transform: translateY(-50%);` because the line looks vertically off-center at greater zooms.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have few more questions regarding this, how  can I add top to the lines as I dont want them exactly at the center of the text I want them slightly at the bottom. Also how can I add space at the beginning and end of the lines.

Comment: Is t possible for you to share a shape or sample drawing to show exactly what you want ?

Comment: |    ___________    some text   ________________________    |.   Some thing like this "|" being the border of the screen. I want to add space between start of the line and border of the panel..same for the end of the line